# Ler um arquivo e encontrar 0 e 1, e converter para True e False em python

Tags: python, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Fiz uma migração de **sqllite3** para **postgres**, porém na migração os atributos booleanos ficam como **0 e 1**, mas quero eles como **True e False**. Desse modo, quero criar um script capaz de ler o arquivo especificamente os **INSERT INTO** do arquivo .sql e trocar o 0 e 1 para False e True.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
exploradorDeArq = filedialog.askopenfilename()
if exploradorDeArq.replace(" ","")!="":
   arquivoOriginal = open(exploradorDeArq ,"r")
   arquivoCopia = arquivoOriginal.readlines()
   arquivoMod = open("ArquivoMOD1.sql","w")

   #Descobrir linha onde está os inserts
   for linhaNumero, linha in enumerate(arquivoCopia, 1): 
       if "INSERT INTO" in linha: 
           #print("linha:",linhaNumero)
           if "1" in linha:
               mudar = linha.replace("1", "True")
            
           if "0" in linha:
               mudar = linha.replace("0", "False")
        
           arquivoMod.write(mudar)
            


   arquivoMod.close()
   messagebox.showinfo("Informação de operação...", "Operação concluída")
```

Esse código acessa o banco de dados e procura os **INSERT INTO** que onde estará os 0 e 1 que eu quero mudar para TRUE e FALSE, o problema é que não está mudando e quando muda,por exemplo o 11 fica TrueTrue, sendo que eu só quero que mude se for apenas o número 1 ou 0.

Answer (score 1):

Se o volume de dados não for exorbitante, recomendo evitar de tentar fazer parser de SQL e carregar no PostgreSQL como `integer` usando `0` e `1` mesmo, e depois você pode usar o comando `ALTER TABLE` para modificar para `boolean`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE sua_tabela
  ALTER campo TYPE bool USING (campo::bool);
```

Exemplo completo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sua_tabela(id int, campo int);

INSERT INTO sua_tabela VALUES(1, 0), (2, 1);

SELECT * FROM sua_tabela;
   id | campo 
  ----+-------
    1 |     0
    2 |     1

ALTER TABLE sua_tabela ALTER campo TYPE bool USING (campo::bool);

SELECT * FROM sua_tabela;
   id | campo 
  ----+-------
    1 | f
    2 | t
```